# Kern Individual Letters With JavaScript (using Generated Content)

Tags: javascript, css, selector

I have an anchor tag which is generated with Wordpress from the database, and the font the client uses has poor kerning. I need to be able to select individual letters on the anchor link and add a `margin-right` CSS value to certain letters in the generated text.

How would I go about selecting the 2nd, 3rd, 4th letter etc of the text with Javascript and then add a margin-right value? I really don't know where to start with this?

```
var anchorTag = document.querySelectorAll(".taxonomy a");
```

**NOTE** - I don't have access to the HTML, so cannot wrap the letters in span elements etc. I need to find a way of selecting individual letters with JavaScript if this is possible.

Comment: You cannot select individual characters without wrapping them first as I demonstrated. The wrapping **is** done entirely with javascript, so you don't need any special "access to the HTML". If you can inject the script into the page then that is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each character in a span element with a custom class:

```js
function wrapCharacters(element, prefix) {
  element.innerHTML = element.textContent
    .split('')
    .map(function(char, index) {
      return '<span class="' + (prefix || 'span') + '_' + index + '">' + char + '</span>';
    })
    .join('');
}

document.querySelectorAll('.taxonomy a').forEach(function(element) {
  wrapCharacters(element);
});
```

```css
.taxonomy a .span_3 { margin-right: 1px; }
.taxonomy a .span_4 { margin-right: 3px; }
.taxonomy a .span_5 { margin-right: 3px; }
.taxonomy a .span_6 { margin-right: 7px; }
```

```html
<div class="taxonomy">
   <a href="#">SampleText</a>
</div>
```

Now you can access the individual characters with CSS like this:

```
.taxonomy a .span_0 { margin-right: 1px; }
.taxonomy a .span_1 { margin-right: 4px; }
.taxonomy a .span_2 { margin-right: 2px; }
```

ES6 Version

```
const wrapCharacters = (element, prefix) =>
  element.innerHTML = element.textContent
    .split('')
    .map((char, index) => `<span class="${prefix || 'span'}_${index}">${char}</span>`)
    .join('');
```